# Is there a better way of finding non-empty tiles in a tilemap?

Tags: unity-game-engine

So the way I did it was an O(n) solution:

```
public static int GetNumberOfTiles(Tilemap tilemap)
    {
        tilemap.CompressBounds();
        TileBase[] tiles = tilemap.GetTilesBlock(tilemap.cellBounds);
        return tiles.Where(x => x != null).ToArray().Length;
    }
```

Is there a way of doing it for O(1) or less code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## No

You can't look at every tile any faster than looking at every tile at least once.

Comment: If you place/remove tiles yourself, then you could keep track of the count.. Also LINQ+toarray could be marginally slower than manual for-loop for counting.

Comment: @mgear True enough, `.Count(...)` would be better and one could certainly track additions/removals manually (depending on what his use-case is). But unless there's a performance problem, both of these changes are nearly meaningless. The to-array part would only have a worst-case time complexity of O(n), combined with the `Where`'s O(n), but O(n)+O(n)=O(n)